# Select clause returns same value for different columns

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, alias, rounding, nan

I'm using native request to select data from two tables.
When I execute my request on pgAdmin console, the result returned well, but when I execute request from my application, same value returned for all columns when I use round() function.
below the request

```
SELECT s.id, 
       p.nom, 
       p.prenom, 
       round(s.column1, 2), 
       round(s.column2, 2), 
       round(s.column3,2) 
FROM table1 s 
   INNER JOIN table2 p USING (id) 
where s.id_type = 2 
and s.id_example=7 
ORDER BY p.nom, p.prenom
```

When I execute this request, If `round(s.column1, 2)` returns `20` as value, I have the same value for `round(s.column2, 2)` and `round(s.column3,2)`.
I tried to use aliases but I received the following exception:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Mauvaise valeur pour le type BigDecimal : NaN

Comment: You're developing your app with Java? Any code snippet that reveals how you handle the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell without you showing more code…

The error is basically complaining that `NaN` (aka not a number) is not a valid value for the [`BigDecimal` type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), which I understand as Java's equivalent to Postgres' `numeric` type.

Postgres accepts `NaN` for the float and arbitrary precision types, but not for integer types:

```
denis=# select 'NaN'::float;
 float8 
--------
    NaN
(1 row)

denis=# select 'NaN'::numeric;
 numeric 
---------
     NaN
(1 row)

denis=# select 'NaN'::bigint;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "NaN"
LINE 1: select 'NaN'::bigint;
               ^
```

As such, it's probably an indication that your ID columns are not integers, that you've incorrectly configured your ORM in such a way that columns are mapped to incorrect equivalent Java types, or that you've some values in your table (`NaN`) that Java doesn't support and that — I'm guessing… — should in fact be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably **two independent problems** here.

The **first** one is most probably a **problem of JDBC**.
`org.postgresql.util` indicates you are using the JDBC Driver - which you should have declared in your question!

If you don't add **column aliases**, all three `round()` calls end up with the same default column alias `round`. The current JDBC is not very smart about that and silently swallows all but the first column for a set of duplicate names.

pgAdmin *allows* identical column names. That's why the same query seems to work there. that's nice for ad-hoc queries, but for anything serious you *must* provide **unique column names** anyway. Try:

```
SELECT s.id, 
       p.nom, 
       p.prenom, 
       round(s.column1, 2) AS col1,
       round(s.column2, 2) AS col2, 
       round(s.column3, 2) AS col3 
FROM   table1 s 
JOIN   table2 p USING (id) 
where  s.id_type = 2 
and    s.id_example = 7 
ORDER  BY p.nom, p.prenom
```

SQL Fiddle also uses JDBC, that's why the following demo can reproduce the problem:
[**SQL Fiddle demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2f03c/4)

The **second** problem is `NaN`. Refer to [@Denis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23083100/939860) for that.
In addition, note that [the Postgres `round()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) with two parameters is only defined for the `numeric` data type.